# Subgroup of index $n$ induces subgroup of size $n$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In working with groups I have come across a lot of special cases of this theorem which seems like it should be true, but I can't seem to prove it (even in the Abelian case):

Given a group $G$ with $H \triangleleft G$ and $[G:H] = n$, then $\exists K \leq G$ such that $G/H \cong K$, and therefore $|K| = n$.

Does anyone know if this is true?

Comment: Notice that this is wrong is general : $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ can't be isomorphic to a subgroup $K$ of $G=\Bbb Z$, since it has an element of order $2$.

Comment: Let $Q_8$ be the quaternion group. Then the $3$ non trivial elements of $Q_8/\{±1\}$ have order $2$, but $Q_8$ has only $1$ element of order $2$ (namely $-1$).

Comment: All the groups I've been working with are Abelian and finite, could it be true in that case? I have a feeling it might fall out of the classification of abelian groups and direct products of cyclic groups, but I haven't been able to get a proof of it in that case either.

Comment: Or what about if H is cyclic and G is finite, but not necessarily abelian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.  As a counterexample, consider the group $G=SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ and the center $H=\{\pm I\} \triangleleft G$.  Then $G$ has order $24$, but has no subgroup of order $|G|/|H|=12$ (see http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_linear_group:SL(2,3)#Table_classifying_subgroups_up_to_automorphism; probably the quickest way to verify there is no subgroup of order $12$ is observe that such a subgroup would be a normal subgroup of index $2$, so it would need to be a union of conjugacy classes which includes all elements of odd order, but there is no collection of such conjugacy classes whose sizes add up to $12$).

Comment: Do you know about the finite Abelian case?

Comment: It is true for finite abelian groups, basically by the classification.  If you write $G$ as a direct sum of cyclic $p$-groups, then any subgroup will be a direct sum of cyclic $p$-groups which can be matched up with the summands of $G$ such that they have smaller exponents of $p$.  But any such group can also be found as a subgroup of $G$, just by taking a subgroup of each summand of $G$.

Comment: (The statement that you can match up the cyclic summands of $H$ with the cyclic summands of $G$ in this way is not obvious; you can prove it by counting how many elements of order $p^n$ $H$ has for each $n$, for instance.  Those counts completely determine the orders of the cyclic summands of $H$, and must be smaller than the corresponding counts for $G$, which you can show means you can match up the summands in this way.)

Comment: The example by Watson in the very first comment below the question is probably one of the simplest and most elementary counter examples: $$2\Bbb Z\le\Bbb Z\;\;\text{and}\;\;\left|\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\right|=2\;,\;\text{but clearly}\;\;\Bbb Z$$ has no subgroup of order two...

Comment: @DonAntonio: but for finite groups the simplest example should be $Q_8$, I believe.

Comment: $Q_8$ is a counterexample to the existence of a $K$ isomorphic to $G/H$, but not to the existence of any subgroup of order $[G:H]$.  I'm not sure if my example is minimal for this stronger property, but I suspect it might be.

Answer (score 2):

In case like you mention you would be interested in the notion of [(short) exact sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ShortExactSequence.html). In the case you mention one has the exact sequence: $$0 {\rightarrow} H \stackrel{i}\rightarrow  G \stackrel{\pi}\rightarrow G/H \rightarrow 0  $$
In some cases the sequence is split (see [split extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Classifying_split_extensions)). This means that there exists a homomorphism $\sigma: G/H \rightarrow G$ such that $\pi \circ \sigma = 1_{G/K} $. If this is the case then your "theorem" is true, with $K = \sigma(G/K)$. Moreover $G$  will be expressible as a semi-direct product $G = H \rtimes K$. But there are cases when the sequence does not split as in the examples given in the comments. The simplest abelian case I know is:  $$ C_2 \rightarrow C_4 \stackrel{a^2}\rightarrow  C_2 $$.